# JavaScript .map not rendering chrome.topSites in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to render a list of titles from Chrome's topSites api for a chrome extension.

When I log it to the console I get this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Chrome Web Store",
    "url": "https://chrome.google.com/webstore?hl=en"
  }
]
```

However, the following doesn't render anything to the page

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        chrome.topSites.get(data => {
          console.log(data);

          data.map(site => {
            return (
              <li key={site.title}>
                {site.title}
              </li>
            );
          });
        })
      }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Expected output: 
A `p` tag with the title of the site gets rendered to the screen

Actual output: 
Nothing is rendered on screen

Comment: You need to add `return` before the `data.map(site => { ... })` as well.

Comment: **Callbacks in extension API are invoked asynchronously** so returning a value from them won't return it into the outer context. I don't know React but you'll have to rework the code - for example so that the callback only sets the state, and move chrome.topSites.get call out of render()

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks. I moved chrome.topSites out to the componentDidMount and set the state when it mounted and used the component's state to map the list on the page

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working for me. Moving `chrome.topSites.get into`componendDidMount()`and assigning it to state. Then mapping the`this.state.sites` to the page in the render method.

```
export default class TopSites extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      sites: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    chrome.topSites.get(data => {
      this.setState({
        sites: data
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {sites} = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {sites.map(site => {
          return (
            <li key={site.title}>
              {site.title}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
state= {
  data: '',
 }

// declaring a async function 
getData = async () => {
        const result = await chrome.topSites.get(); // waiting for the result
 this.setState({ data: result});
 }

componentDidMount(){
  this.getData();
}


 render(){
 const list = this.state.data ? this.state.data.map((val) => <li key={val.title}> {val.title}
    </li> : null)
return(
     <ul>
     {list}
    </ul>

 )
}
```